# TensorFlow: change tanh of BasicRNNCell to another op?

Tags: python, inheritance, neural-network, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I want try some other transfer functions besides the default `tanh` in TensorFlow's `BasicRNNCell`.

The original implementation is like:

```
class BasicRNNCell(RNNCell):
(...)
def __call__(self, inputs, state, scope=None):
    """Most basic RNN: output = new_state = tanh(W * input + U * state + B)."""
    with vs.variable_scope(scope or type(self).__name__):  # "BasicRNNCell"
      output = tanh(linear([inputs, state], self._num_units, True))
    return output, output
```

...and I changed it to:

```
class MyRNNCell(BasicRNNCell):
(...)
def __call__(self, inputs, state, scope=None):
    """Most basic RNN: output = new_state = tanh(W * input + U * state + B)."""
    with tf.variable_scope(scope or type(self).__name__):  # "BasicRNNCell"
      output = my_transfer_function(linear([inputs, state], self._num_units, True))
    return output, output
```

Changing `vs.variable_scope` to `tf.variable_scope`, was successful but `linear` is an implementation in > **[rnn_cell.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py)** < and not available in `tf` itself.

How can I get this to work?

Do I have to re-implement `linear` completely? (I already checked the code, I think I would run into dependency problems there, too...)

Comment: I am unfamiliar with tensor flow, but tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell is not a builtin/base class. You ought to be able to extend the class or "punch" a new method into the existing class so that all dependencies in the class are available.  So, I'm not sure why you wish to change vs.variable_scope to tf.variable_scope.  Could you explain what you need from tf.variable_scope ?  eg: How is "my_transfer_function" implemented ?

Comment: `vs` is not visible, thus I get `global name vs is not defined` when running the script. That's the reason why I changed `vs` to `tf`, because the the method `variable_scope` is present in `tf`. However, `linear` is a local function in that file, therefore it complains that `linear` is missing when I run my script. Hence, my question is how would I satisfy this dependency?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to change the code of the tensor flow implementation for this.

The BasicRNNCell has a parameter called activation function. You can just simply change that from tf.tanh to whatever activation function you want.